# Cross reference two data sources for matches in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Firstly, thank you for checking my quesiton.  I'm new to doing anything advanced in Excel so I'm a bit lost.

I am trying to match names from two different sources that have the same data structure.  There are 3 columns, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName.  I added a fourth row to denote which organization the record came from and put both sources into one table and made a pivot out of it which works well enough but I'm having a hard time generating any useful data from it.

There are two main objectives once I have them matched.
I need a percentage of matching.
I need to be able to filter out the ones that matched so I can investigate the ones that didn't.

Here is a small example.

```
+-------------+-----------+------------+------+
|  LastName   | FirstName | MiddleName | Org. |
+-------------+-----------+------------+------+
| Jones       | Mike      | Anthony    | Org1 |
| Black       | Marry     |            | Org1 |
| Zeek        | Winston   | E          | Org1 |
| Jones       | Mike      | A          | Org2 |
| Black-Smith | Marry     |            | Org2 |
| Zeek        | Winston   | E          | Org2 |
+-------------+-----------+------------+------+
```

As you can see out of the list only Winston E Zeek would really match because all three names are exactly the same.  Mike Jones won't match because the listed middle names are wrong and Black and Black-Smith won't match because they are technically different last names.  These issues with the data are fine at this stage because those are exactly what I'm trying to identify with a larger data set.

Maybe Excel isn't the best for this issue without using VBA?  I'm not familiar with VBA which is why I haven't tried it yet and I unfortunately have limited time.

How can I solve this matching problem?
Any assistance and guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick idea:

1. Sort the data by last name, first name, middle name.  That should put same/similar names next to each other.
2. Add a column that, for each row, has a worksheet function like =IF(A3=A2,1,0).  This will indicate if this row matches the one above.
3. Sum the new column... That will tell you the number of matches.  Divide by the total number of rows, to get your percentage.

You can modify the function in step 2, to indicate as tight of a match that you want.

Advantage:  No VBA needed.  Disadvantage:  It requires some manual work and interpretation.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  After trying it, I determined the pivot actually was more useful in this situation for me.  I copied the data from the pivot after I made some changes and filtered parts of the results.  It is still cumbersome but short of more advanced programming, I think this is the best I can do.  Thanks again.